# Does MySQL allow to specify table for a group of selectors?

Tags: mysql

MySQL syntax that I know to explicitly specify table for the column that you are selecting:

```
SELECT p1.first, p1.last FROM people p1 /* JOIN */;
```

However, does MySQL allow syntax ~ (see below) that would achieve the same result?

```
SELECT p1 (first, last) FROM people p1 /* JOIN */;
```

The common problem that I run into is where I already have a concatenated string representing SELECT statement, though I need to prefix the values, e.g. my string would be `first, last`, though the actual query would expect `p1.first, p1.last`. The described scenario is at the program level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that, no, this is not allowed.

You really need to be careful when building queries with concatenated strings such that you don't expose SQL injection vulnerabilities (if those strings contain data input from users).

Comment: None of that is user input. I am getting it from `information_schema`. As far as I can read from the documentation, I don't see a solution either. Thoough, I don't see good reason why MySQL shouldn't support it either.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas So you are trying to build queries dynamically using information_schema?  You have the table information available there as well, why not just concatenate the full table name along with the field name when building your string?  This would eliminate needs for table alias altogether.

Comment: What if the table is used more than once within the query? ie self-join. The other alternative is to use a predefined string for the alias.

Answer (score 1):

There's no syntax to do what you're asking, but you only have to qualify column names for non-unique columns.  If the `first` and `last` columns exist *only* on `p1`, then just the `p1.` is not needed.

If that's not the case, then if you are joining on specific columns you can use `USING` to get around this.  For example:

```
SELECT first, last FROM people p1 JOIN people p2 USING (first, last)
```

is valid.  If you used `ON` instead, you would still have to qualify the column names, though.

If the columns exist in multiple tables and you're not joining on them, then you are stuck qualifying the column names in the field list.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to "inject" a table alias into a pre-constructed column list, you could just try something like this:

```
CONCAT(table_alias, '.', REPLACE(column_list, ', ', CONCAT(', ', table_alias, '.')))
```

i.e. replace every comma + space in the list with a comma + space + table alias followed by a `.`, also adding the alias with a `.` at the beginning of the list. This, of course, assumes that the list doesn't end with a comma + space.

And please, *please* don't tell me you've got commas in column names!

Comment: That might be a solution for some. Too dirty for me. I ended up hand/hard coding table alias for every model. The short answer to the original question remains – MySQL doesn't support such syntax.

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider accepting one of the other two answers, each of which explicitly addresses your direct question.